# PyTorch memory leak on loss.backward on both gpu as well as cpu

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I've tried everything. gc.collect, torch.cuda.empty_cache, deleting every possible tensor and variable as soon as it is used, setting batch size to 1, nothing seems to work.

I'm working on text to code generation problem and utilizing the code from this repository : [TranX](https://github.com/pcyin/tranX)

I've rewritten the data loader, model training pipeline and have made it as simple as i possibly can, but somehow it always runs out of memory.

Here's my data loader :

```py
class DSET:
    def __init__(self, load_file='', mode='train', batch_size=16):
        self.load_file = load_file
        self.data = open(self.load_file, 'r', encoding='utf8').readlines()

        class EXAMPLE(object):
            def __init__(self, examples):
                self._examples = examples
                self.generator = AST('python')

            def generate_ast(self, code_text):
                tree = self.generator.generate_ast(code_text)
                return tree

            def get_actions(self, ast_tree):
                actions = self.generator.get_actions(ast_tree)
                return actions

            def __getitem__(self, index):
                line = json.loads(self._examples[index])

                try:
                    canonical_intent, slot_map = canonicalize_intent(
                        line['nl'])

                    canonical_code = canonicalize_code(line['code'], slot_map)
                    intent_tokens = tokenize_intent(canonical_intent)

                    python_ast = ast.parse(canonical_code)

                    canonical_code_source = astor.to_source(python_ast).strip()
                    target_ast = self.generate_ast(python_ast)

                    target_actions = self.get_actions(target_ast)

                    target_action_infos = get_action_infos(
                        intent_tokens, target_actions)

                    example = Example(src_sent=intent_tokens,
                                      tgt_actions=target_action_infos,
                                      tgt_code=canonical_code_source,
                                      tgt_ast=target_ast,
                                      meta=dict(example_dict=line,
                                                slot_map=slot_map))
                except Exception as e:
                    example = Example(src_sent=[''],
                                      tgt_actions=[None],
                                      tgt_code=[''],
                                      tgt_ast=None,
                                      meta={})

                return example

            def __setitem__(self, index, value):
                pass

        self.examples = EXAMPLE(self.data)

        self.num_examples = len(self.data)
        self.example_indices = np.arange(self.num_examples)
        self.iterator = 0
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_steps = self.num_examples // self.batch_size

    def batch_iter(self):
        indices = self.example_indices[self.iterator *
                                       self.batch_size:(self.iterator + 1) *
                                       self.batch_size]

        x = []

        for idx in indices:
            sample = self.examples[idx]
            x.append(sample)

        self.iterator += 1

        if self.iterator > len(self.example_indices) // self.batch_size:
            self.iterator = 0
            np.random.shuffle(self.example_indices)

        x.sort(key=lambda e: -len(e.src_sent))

        return x

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_examples
```

Here's my training code :

```py
def train(args):

    train_set = DSET(args.train_file, mode='train', batch_size=args.batch_size)

    validation_set = DSET(args.dev_file,
                          mode='valid',
                          batch_size=args.batch_size)

    vocab = pickle.load(open(args.vocab, 'rb'))

    grammar = ASDLGrammar.from_text(open(args.asdl_file).read())

    transition_system = Registrable.by_name(args.transition_system)(grammar)

    parser = Registrable.by_name(args.parser)

    model = parser(args, vocab, transition_system)

    model.train()

    evaluator = Registrable.by_name(args.evaluator)(transition_system,
                                                    args=args)

    if args.cuda:
        model.cuda()

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)

    nn_utils.glorot_init(model.parameters())

    print('Begining Training ...')
    print(
        f'Training Examples : {len(train_set)}, Validation Examples : {len(validation_set)}'
    )

    print(
        f'Number Of Epochs : {args.max_epoch}, Steps Per Epoch : {train_set.num_steps}, Batch Size : {args.batch_size}'
    )

    total_steps = 0

    for e in range(args.max_epoch):
        start_time = time.time()

        for iter in range(train_set.num_steps):
            total_steps += 1
            loss_val = 0

            batch = train_set.batch_iter()

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            loss = -model.score(batch)

            loss = torch.mean(loss)

            if iter % args.log_every == 0:
                loss_val = torch.sum(loss).detach().item()
                print(f'Iteration : {iter}, Loss : {loss_val}')

            loss.backward(retain_graph=False)

            optimizer.step()

            del loss
            del loss_val
            del batch

            gc.collect()

            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

            time.sleep(2)

        print(f'Epoch {e} : Time Taken : {time.time() - start_time}')

        model_file = args.save_to + '/' + f'model.epoch_{e}.bin'

        print(f'Saved Model To : {model_file}')

        model.save(model_file)

        torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(),
                   args.save_to + '/' + f'model_{e}.optim.bin')

        # Run Validation

        print('Running Validation...')

        try:
            eval_results = evaluate(validation_set.examples,
                                    model,
                                    evaluator,
                                    args,
                                    verbose=False,
                                    eval_top_pred_only=args.eval_top_pred_only)

            validation_score = eval_results[evaluator.default_metric]

            print(f'Evaluation Score: {validation_score}')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Could not validate: {e}')
            pass
```

**The model.score method is custom by the repo author and i've added delete and gc.collect and torch.cuda.empty_cache lines throughout**

I'm running pytorch 1.9.1 with cuda 11.1 on a 16gb GPU instance on aws ec2 with 32gb ram and ubuntu 18.04

I've re-written the code to make it more efficient as the code in the repository loaded the whole bin file of the dataset at once.

But i can't train the model, even with batch size of 1.

With batch size of 8, it crashes after 46 iterations, with batch size of 1 it goes upto 48k iterations but then crashes.

Traceback for GPU (After 46 Iterations):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 150, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "train.py", line 98, in train
    loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/comet_ml/monkey_patching.py", lin                                                                                                                     e 312, in wrapper
    return_value = original(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 255, in b                                                                                                                     ackward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=i                                                                                                                     nputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line                                                                                                                      149, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 7.27 GiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB t                                                                                                                     otal capacity; 10.46 GiB already allocated; 2.98 GiB free; 10.52 GiB reserved in                                                                                                                      total by PyTorch)
```

Traceback for CPU (It simply says Killed) but goes upto iteration 672:

```
Iteration : 672, Loss : 702.1222534179688
Killed
```

Running dmesg gives the following output

```
[2059991.491436] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,me                                                                                                                     ms_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice,task=python3,pid=25315,uid=0
[2059991.491542] Out of memory: Killed process 25315 (python3) total-vm:53312244                                                                                                                     kB, anon-rss:31451456kB, file-rss:74816kB, shmem-rss:12296kB, UID:0 pgtables:690                                                                                                                     68kB oom_score_adj:0
[2059992.056260] oom_reaper: reaped process 25315 (python3), now anon-rss:0kB, f                                                                                                                     ile-rss:74732kB, shmem-rss:12296kB
```

Pytorch dataset and dataloader :

```py
class T_DSET(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, load_file='', mode='train'):
        self.load_file = load_file
        self.data = open(self.load_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
        self.generator = AST('python')

    def generate_ast(self, code_text):
        tree = self.generator.generate_ast(code_text)
        return tree

    def get_actions(self, ast_tree):
        actions = self.generator.get_actions(ast_tree)
        return actions

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        line = json.loads(self.data[idx])

        try:
            canonical_intent, slot_map = canonicalize_intent(line['nl'])

            canonical_code = canonicalize_code(line['code'], slot_map)
            intent_tokens = tokenize_intent(canonical_intent)

            python_ast = ast.parse(canonical_code)

            canonical_code_source = astor.to_source(python_ast).strip()
            target_ast = self.generate_ast(python_ast)

            target_actions = self.get_actions(target_ast)

            target_action_infos = get_action_infos(intent_tokens,
                                                   target_actions)

            example = Example(src_sent=intent_tokens,
                              tgt_actions=target_action_infos,
                              tgt_code=canonical_code_source,
                              tgt_ast=target_ast,
                              meta=dict(example_dict=line, slot_map=slot_map))
        except Exception as e:
            example = Example(src_sent=[''],
                              tgt_actions=[None],
                              tgt_code=[''],
                              tgt_ast=None,
                              meta={})

        return example


def example_batch(batch):
    return batch

train_set = T_DSET(args.train_file, mode='train')

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_set,
                              batch_size=args.batch_size,
                              shuffle=True,
                              collate_fn=example_batch)
```

Traceback (Iteration 39) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 166, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "train.py", line 107, in train
    loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/comet_ml/monkey_patching.py", line 312, in wrapper
    return_value = original(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 255, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 149, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 8.09 GiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 10.98 GiB already allocated; 2.50 GiB free; 11.00 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/4685471) (tl;dr: **never** - edited out).

Comment: @abtExp This is strange since you don't seem to have any memory leaks and the error persists on CPU. Could you explain why you have `EXAMPLE` inside `DSET`. Why didn't you use Dataset/DataLoader combination instead?

Comment: @Ivan I'm a noob in pytorch as i mostly use tensorflow. So i coded this EXAMPLE class which will generate the required object on call, do you think the dataset and dataloader combination would help? if yes, i can try and use them.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. You can have a look [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) to get an idea of how they work.

Comment: @Ivan i even tried monitoring the GPU usage using nvidia-smi during training, the memory get's cleaned after each iteration, but after every 2 or 3 iterations, the memory being filled increases and then cleaned, but after some iterations (like 46 in this case of batch size 8), it suddenly allocates a lot of memory and it goes out of memory.

Comment: @Ivan, ok, i'll try with dataset and dataloaders as well. Thanks for the suggestion, i'll get back to you.

Comment: @Ivan Didn't work. It stopped even earlier. on iteration 39, i've added the code and the traceback for pytorch dataloader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238130/discussion-between-abtexp-and-ivan).

Comment: Can you try running your training loop without the model inference and back propagation? And see if it fails, it might be related to a leak *inside* the dataset.

Comment: @Ivan If you mean just running the data loader and load batches for all iterations, I've tried that, it works fine

Comment: Have you tried running with random inputs, *i.e.* replacing your current dataset with a mock which returns random data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I couldn't find you using `.to(device)` or `.to(cuda)` on your data. it should be in your training loop where you move your data to GPU. if you are keeping your entire data in GPU, and making copies of it, it may create problems down the line.

second please check your model and evaluation code as well. if you are detaching variables outside the main training loop it may create issue. right now I can say you have some extra pieces of code in your training loop. I am adding some comments to your training loop code. but I think the actual problem lies in either the validation code or the Network itself.

```py
    for e in range(args.max_epoch):
    start_time = time.time()

    # instead of this: for iter in range(train_set.num_steps):
    # use this as train_loader itself an iterator.
    for example in train_loader:
        total_steps += 1
        loss_val = 0

        # instead of batch = train_set.batch_iter()
        batch = example.to(device)  # moving data to GPU
        # but in your case you need to loop through the dictionary
        # move each value inside a loop.

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss = -model.score(batch)

        loss = torch.mean(loss)

        if iter % args.log_every == 0:
            # no need to detach this variable as long as you don't call
            # backward on it, it's fine.
            loss_val = torch.sum(loss).detach().item()
            print(f'Iteration : {iter}, Loss : {loss_val}')

        loss.backward(retain_graph=False)

        optimizer.step()

        # I don't think deleting them will help as it's the
        # end of the for loop they will get deleted anyway
        del loss
        del loss_val
        del batch
        
        # generally you call these methods at the
        # beginning of the code and at the ending of your code. here it doesn't make any sense.
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()

        # I don't know why you have this, I mean its going to
        # slowdown the training
        time.sleep(2)
```

Also, use [Nvidia Nsight Systems](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems) for a deeper look into your code. hope this is helpful.